# Error in matching condition that letters 'b' should have atleast one leading a using regex python. How to rectify it?

Tags: python, regex

I coded using python to match the following condition
re pattern that identifies  the language over the alphabet {a, b} of all strings in which each 'b' is preceded by at least one 'a'

```
import re

s = '''
a
aaaa
ab
aba
abaabaaaab
b
abb
bba
'''

regex =  re.finditer(r"^([aA]+[bB]?)+", s, re.M)
for i in regex:
    print(i.group())
```

I'm getting 'ab' at output from 'abb' on 7th line of multi line string. But it should not happen. I don't want it in output. What change must be done in regular expression to rectify this error.

Comment: You want `(?i)^(?:a+b?)+$`.

Comment: Try this, ```re.findall("^[a-b]+", s, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)```

Comment: No brother (Sushanth) yours condition not working while Wiktor brothers is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$` to the end of your regex:

```
^([aA]+[bB]?)+$
```

Whereas `^` marks the start of line, `$` marks its end. This way you are forcing a match over the entire line, not just a part of it.